# Why is my Gap property in SCSS not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, nextjs-image

I'm trying to put a gap on these icons to look appealing however it does not work. Which line did I go wrong with it? I've tried putting `gap:20px;` on both navlinks and icon divs still no changes.

Here's my SCSS

```
.navbar-container{
    background-color:$color--navyblue;
    width: 105px;
    height: 100vh;
    border-right: solid white 2px;
}
.SysDev-Logo{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 25px;
}
.navlinks{
    margin: 0;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 25px;

    .icon{
        list-style: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
}
```

And my nextjs

```
<div className={styles['navbar-container']}>
            <div className="container-wrapper">
                <div className="Logo-wrapper">
                    <div className={styles['SysDev-Logo']}>
                        <Image
                            src="/img/SysDev LogoType.png"
                            width="50"
                            height="45"
                            objectFit="contain"
                            draggable="false"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul className={styles['navlinks']}>
                    <li className={[styles['icon'], styles['icon--home']].join(' ')}>
                        <Image
                            src="/img/home.svg"
                            width="50"
                            height="50"
                            objectFit="contain"
                            draggable="false"
                        />
                    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]- preferrably in the form of a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541).

Comment: Have you looked using you browsers devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied to each element? That should show you what if anything is overriding any gap you have set.

Comment: You have not applied `display: grid` or `display: flex` to your container. The `gap` property only has any effect in grid or flex containers.